# Create instance of symbol exported for actionscript in loaded SWF

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

In a flash project, I am loading an external SWF that has some symbols in its library exported for ActionScript. I need to create instances of those symbols but, since it's a loaded SWF I don't have direct access to that classes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there are several ways of doing this.

The nicest could be this:

```
var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener("complete", ldrDone);
ldr.load(new URLRequest("external.swf"));

function ldrDone(evt:*):void
{
    var externalclass:Class = evt.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition("ExternalClass") as Class;
    var temp:MovieClip = new externalclass();
    addChild(temp);
}
```

Where `ExternalClass` is the exported classname in the external swf.

Or, simply use a function in your external movie, where you return the specific objects on demand.

Like put this in your external swf:

```
function getThisClass():*
{
     return new MyClass();
}
```

This is not that awesome as the first one, but could lead to other ideas too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: do you use ExternalClass.as or just the ExternalClass if the actual file name is ExternalClass.as?